# Blender 2.79b errors with addons

Tags: error

I keep getting errors installing addons in Blender 2.79b this is the most recent for IK-Particles addon. Any help would be great. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: For pay to use addons suggest using the support provided.

Comment: Agree with above comment, but it seems a "file not found" or "platform mismatch" about some dll, seeing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/