# Addons being rejected by blender

Tags: add-on, error

Good day. My blender version ,  2.79 , is currently rejecting all my external add ons. This is the first time that this is happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115005/blender-2-79b-errors-with-addons